# Getting the path of a url on GET before it's redirected to undefined if it doesn't exist as a static page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I'm building a simple URL shortener and learning Node.JS and Express while I'm doing it - I've got some code that looks like this in my only non-index.js file (in the routes directory):

```
/* GET URL listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Get short URL passed in
  shortURL = req.originalUrl.substring(1);

  // Get Long URL from short URL
  var newURL = getLongURL(shortURL);

  // Navigate to Long URL
  redirectLink(res, newURL);
});
```

I know the getLongURL and redirectLink methods work - but because of how I'm getting the path, it automatically goes to 'undefined' before I can get the path so the shortURL is always 'undefined'.

I'm looking for functionality like this:

url = www.example.com/12345 : I want shortURL = 12345

The way I'm doing the routing in my app.js file is as follows:

```
var urls = require('./routes/urls');
app.use('/*', urls);
```

Comment: Use the var keyword, `var shortUrl= .. `

Comment: @teleaziz Sorry that was a typo - it's defined in a more global scope but I've refactored it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand you well, you problem is that `req.originalUrl` equals to `undefined` because of how you "get the path". If yes, can you provide the code of your index.js, especially the part responsible for "getting the path"?